# Macro or c++ template to change const variable value in struct or class

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, variadic-macros

I’m implementing a protocol in C++, and it’s an ongoing project therefore the protocol changes frequently, and I have to change the code accordingly.

Let’s say I define a message as follows:

```cpp
struct Message {
  const int MSG_LENGTH = 3; // sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)
  uint8_t a;
  uint16_t b;
};
```

Now I want to add a new field `uint32_t c` into `Message`, but I don’t want to manually change `MSG_LENGTH`.

Is it possible to use some trick (macro or template) to achieve this?

Thanks.

Comment: Assuming the code in your question is the actual code, then just use `sizeof(struct Message)`

Comment: What you ask is not possible, though, why don't you use `sizeof(Message)`? Also with that you avoid having a copy of the number `3` in each instance of `Message`.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield Thanks for the reply. It’s not actual code, and indeed the Message will inherit from another base struct MessageBase which contains some other member variables, therefore sizeof(Message) is not applicable.

Comment: Then you could use `sizeof(Message) - sizeof(MessageBase)`.

Comment: @jabaa that will not work generally

Comment: If you don't want to change the value _manually_, why is `sizeof(a) + sizeof(b)` commented out? Surely there's some way that you can use `sizeof` to determine the size of a structure

Comment: Without some kind of serialization step this struct won't make any sense by itself. You may want to think in terms of templates for automatically encoding these and generating the struct in the first place.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield -- the two are not required to be the same, and usually they are not. Structs have padding between and after their fields, so the size of a struct will often be greater than the sum of the sizes of its members.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Initially, this was tagged with the [c] tag, and as I pointed out, the suggestion is dependent on the specified code being the actual code. In C, for that code, the prevalent platforms would not pad that structure.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield -- "the **prevalent platforms** would not pad that structure" -- that's my point: this is not **required** to work.

Comment: No reflection yet in c++, but some library offer syntax to add it (`BOOST_FUSION_DEFINE_STRUCT`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_76_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/define_struct.html)), and then you can iterate over members. [`magic_get`](https://github.com/apolukhin/magic_get) is an alternative if your struct has "good" properties.

Answer (score 2):

One idea could be to define the messages in form of `std::tuple`s:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template<class... Types>
struct MessageBase : std::tuple<Types...> {
    static constexpr size_t MSG_LENGTH() {
        return (sizeof(Types) + ...);       // calc the size of the fields
    }
};

struct Message : MessageBase<uint8_t, uint16_t> {};

int main() {
    constexpr auto x = Message::MSG_LENGTH();

    std::cout << x << '\n'; //  prints 3
}
```